# iOS 8: Autorotation is not working without storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I am trying to start a project w/o Storyboards and I can't seem to figure out why the UIWindow is not passing autorotation commands to the root view controller.  With storyboards, the autorotation works.  If I create the window programmatically, autorotation does not work.

[image: screenshot]

This is how I instantiate the window in the App Delegate:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
if let window = window {
    window.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let nc: SignInViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            .instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInViewController") as SignInViewController
    window.rootViewController = nc
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm using Xcode 6.1.

Comment: i have the issue in both Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) and Version 6.1 (6A1052d), so i don't think it has to do with Xcode

Comment: I think this problem is still open; I get the exact same problem with Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b). Unless I launch with a storyboard, rotation does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked answer is to downgrade to XCode 6.0.1 - I do not recommend it.

1) If you **do not use storyboards** **(Answer for this topic !!)**

Go to -> Project Name -> Targets -> Project Name -> Deployment Info -> **Main Interface -> Make it Empty**

---

2) In case you **use storyboards** (not the main answer)

your AppDelegate should look like ...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    return true
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster, and the problem occurs even when the Main Interface is set as empty.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using storyboards? If so, you may have old code in your application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Try removing the following line of code and any others to do with UIWindow:

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Just need to remove above line from AppDelegate.m file.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is correct and you are seeing one (of many) bugs of XCode 6.1.

I tried a very simple app with 6.1 using your code and I could experiment the bug. Then I downgraded to 6.0.1 and the autorotation of my app was perfect.

I advice you to downgrade to XCode 6.0.1 and retry your app.

You can download it from here: [Apple Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode)

Comment: Thanks, that's very troubling since Xcode 6.1 is the current release.

Comment: i tried it out in Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317), it did not change anything for me.

Comment: Indeed, for me Xcode version is problematic. Did someone find solution to this? Frustrating.

Comment: I finally found other solution than to downgrade to 6.0.1 Look below for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable the device orientations in the project's General settings

in xcode 6.1, click your main project folder, General tab

Scroll down to Device Orientation, enable "Portrait", "Landscape Left", "Landscape Right"

See [iOS 8.1 auto rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521633/ios-8-1-auto-rotation) for a picture of the Device Orientation settings

Comment: Thanks, I do have that set https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jh0ww0sfjkdzbz/Screenshot%202014-10-23%2019.04.34.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

i just solved the problem in my project.
for me, the solution was to remove the animation from the following code:
`[self presentViewController: root animated: animated completion:^{
    [AppDelegate singleton].window.rootViewController = root;
 }];`

which is now just 
`[AppDelegate singleton].window.rootViewController = root;`

i don't know if this answers your question, but it solved my instance of what i think is a shared problem.