# iPad Orientations in ios 8 and xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

iPad Orientations not working,

// Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {

  NSLog(@"we are here");

  return YES;

}
And also  I have allready setup info.plist. I have 4 items in that array, one for each orientation. –

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in xcode 6.1 around auto rotations.

Here's the answer to your question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26543312/4171538

Comment: Try replacing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` with `shouldAutorotate` as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260261/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-in-ios-6

Comment: I think the issue is in Xcode 6.0 and iOS 8.0 and above. I also try it in Xcode 6.0 but its not working.